# Echo a string into the HTML header

Tags: php, html

This has got my mind twisted. Obviously PHP can't handle something ahead of time before it even knows there is a problem.

I've got this in the header of the document:

```
<? $site = new core(); 
register_shutdown_function(shutdown);
echo $site->insert_to_header(); ?>
```

Then further down, purposely put:

```
echo $test;
```

To create a warning. This gets taken to `shutdown();`, that looks like this:

```
class core {
function shutdown() {
$a = error_get_last();
if ($a == null) {
    echo "No errors";
} else {
    core::insert_to_header_cache('<link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css" type="text/css" />');
    core::insert_to_body_cache('<div class="error-handler"><h3>Error!</h3>
   <br/>Error type: <strong>' . $a[type] . '</strong>
   <br/>Error message: <strong>' . $a[message] . '</strong>
   <br/>Located in: <strong>' . $a[file] . '</strong>
   <br/>Line: <strong>' . $a[line] . '</strong>
   </div>');
}
}
//TODO Teleport variables to here, without doing that beforehand, this whole thing is broken :(
function insert_to_header_cache($insertion ='') {
    $headercache += $insertion . '/n';
    return true;
}

function insert_to_body_cache($insertion ='') {
    $bodycache += $insertion . '/n';
    return true;
}    
function insert_to_header() {
    global $headercache;
    echo $headercache;
    return true;
}

function insert_to_body() {
   global $bodycache;
    return $bodycache;
}
}
```

My problem is, how can I get my `insert_to_header_cache` function to output back up into the header when it's already past that point?

Please keep in mind I realize calling global `$bodycache` and `$headercache` isn't working, but this isn't the issue here. Echoing anything in advance here doesn't work. because of order, I know that much.

Thanks in advance,

Evan Harrison

Comment: You can start with not peppering `echo`s within your controller, instead calling all of your functions to output each block only at the very end, once your processing is finished.

Comment: I've got them peppered all over the place to see what is going on while working on it.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about: http://codepad.org/Ny3Zxk5L Note, this is a very simplistic example, but the overall concept is the same.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that code. That is definitely one way to solve this. It would make my design of a modular theme a little more PHP structured though. Does that make any sense? I'm trying to make it easy to wrap around HTML without needing to put all the code into variables.

Comment: I'm not quite following you from the third sentence on in your comment. Are you looking for possibly a [template system](http://www.smarty.net/)?

Comment: I'm trying to build my own (A basic one). Really your solution would work aside from the fact all the HTML markup is in variables.

I'm thinking, one solution is have a MySQL Back-end that stored the HTML and the PHP could call it and put it in a variable that way, but then I would not be able to use an SVN on a lot of the markup.

Comment: *all the HTML markup is in variables* - What does this mean or refer to?

Comment: I mean in your example, you have this:
<?
 $html = "
<html>
<head>
$styles
$scripts
</head>
<body>
$this->body
</body>
</html>
";
?>

instead of it being something like:

<html>
<head>
<? $site->head($something) ?>
</head>

<body>
<? $site->getbody(); ?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Like I said, that was a simplistic example. I have a class I built some time ago that does this very thing, but it uses Smarty templates to separate display logic from the controller. Just keep in mind, don't begin to construct the actual page until you're completely done processing, so all you're doing is outputting. That's why I use `$page->buildOutput()`, but you could pass another PHP file to that method that represents your actual view. I just happen to pass a Smarty template filename (ie, `echo $html->buildOutput($assigns, 'docShowMeTheMoney.tpl')`).

Comment: Thanks for that. You should paste it as an answer so I can give you points. I've got plenty of ideas on how this can be done now =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to not output anything until all of the processing is complete and any injections of scripts, stylesheets or other resources have been performed on a `Page` object. If you wait until your view is completely ready, then compile the output, you have quite a bit more control over things like script and stylesheets being included in things like `head` tags.

Below is a simplistic example that is only meant to demonstrate what I'm talking about. As we discussed in the comments below the question, you can replace the `buildOutput()` method with a method to instead point to a PHP file that represents your view with calls to return the list of `script` and `stylesheet` URLs, for example.

```
<?php

class page {

    private $head;
    private $body;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->head = array('scripts'=>array(),'styles'=>array());
        $this->body = '';
    }

    public function addStylesheet($link) {
        $this->head['styles'][] = $link;
    }

    public function addScript($link) {
        $this->head['scripts'][] = $link;
    }

    public function setBody($content) {
        $this->body = $content;
    }

    public function buildOutput() {
        $c_styles = count($this->head['styles']);
        $c_scripts = count($this->head['scripts']);
        $styles = '';
        $scripts = '';

        for ($i = 0; $i < $c_styles; $i++) {
            $styles .= '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$this->head['styles'][$i].'" />'."\n";
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $c_scripts; $i++) {
            $scripts .= '<script src="'.$this->head['scripts'][$i].'"></script>'."\n";
        }

        $html = "
<html>
<head>
$styles
$scripts
</head>
<body>
$this->body
</body>
</html>
";
        return $html;
    }

}

$page = new page;

$page->addStylesheet('http://www.example.com/my.css');
$page->addStylesheet('http://www.example.com/their.css');
$page->addScript('http://www.example.com/my.js');
$page->addScript('http://www.example.com/their.js');
$page->setBody('<p>This is my body</p>');

echo $page->buildOutput();

?>
```

http://codepad.org/Ny3Zxk5L

Comment: Cheers for that, It was 2am when I last replied so I went to bed. But never fear, I marked this as the right one!

Answer (score 2):

you can use output buffering. in a few words it allows you to collect all the output in a string before sending it to the client, and at the end you can manipulate the output that you has and finally send it to the client

Comment: Technically, output buffering won't necessarily resolve the issue by itself, simply because the problem is that the header is being output, but then needs to be adjusted at a later point. The resolution is to assemble all of the pieces for the header, and then at the end before the script quits, calling a `buildOutput()` function/method that constructs the header (and all of the other content) at the latest possible moment.

Comment: Does this mean all HTML markup will need to be in variables rather then procedural calls to class functions? Is it even possible to do as I have structured the main page? (I have the classes in a different file to the creation of the object, etc.)

Comment: no, this doesn't mean that. you only have to add  `ob_start` function at the start of the script end at the end of all output you have to call `ob_get_contents` function and doing some modifications with that string and outputting it to client. http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php here you can learn more about that

Comment: @EvanHarrison - Just wondering, why did you change your mind on the marked answer for this question?

Comment: I was looking at this answer from a year ago and didnt realise i could still change the right answer.

Comment: @EvanHarrison - Ok, thanks. I was just wondering why it popped up again this much later. If you think this should be the answer, by all means; don't let me stop you. Did you ever set anything up like in my answer?

Comment: Yeah I did actually. A whole CMS system that I've used for a few projects now!